# Can dynamically loaded functions finish writing the page that dynamically loaded them

Tags: javascript

Please Help.

Question:  Can I dynamically load a JS file (/scripts/banner.js) and then use one of its functions -- writeBanner(document, t1, t2, t3) -- to finish writing the page?

I've read till my eyes bleed, but:

-- Every example I find assumes the reader will call a function AFTER the page is rendered, and

-- Every example assumes blocking is bad.

Unfortunately:

-- I need to call the functions in order to finish writing the page that loaded them, and

-- Blocking is not a problem.  The app is deployed as an EAR file, so no JS files need thereafter be downloaded from anywhere else.

Why try to do this?

The initial window ("TAPP") loads a dozen functions from 6 JS files. All pages use them to write HTML in the page's body element that displays a consistent banner with up to 3 paramaterized title lines.

Level-1 Pages:  These are opened in the initial ("TAPP") window by each other.  It already has all functions loaded – works perfectly.

Level-2 pages: These are opened in pop-up windows opened by level-1 pages.  They use "this.opener", i.e. "TAPP" to call those functions – works perfectly.

Now I want to be able to open Level-2 pages both

-- as pop-ups from a level-2 page, AND

-- as free standing pages.

NOTE:  All level-2 pages.jsp being with this include to write the HEAD element:

```
<%@ include file='/jsp-pages/level-2/headers/beg.jsp' %>
```

That way I only need to deal with scripting for all of them, in one place, at one time.

First Step:  I added this code to beg.jsp:

```
<script language="javascript">
  var SH = "";
  if (this.opener && this.opener.name == "TAPP") {
    SH = this.opener; // TAPP has all required functions
  } else {
    //Dynamically add the required <script> elements
    /************************************/
    // see code I tried below
   /************************************/
   SH = this; // "this" now has all the functions TAPP has
   //        alert ("Opener is NOT TAPP: " + SH);
  }
  // All pages can now call SH.writeBanner(document, t1,t2, t3) with their own titles
</script>
```

Here's the rub.  When the alert () function above is uncommented BOTH tries (DOM and document.write() below) work perfectly.  When it is commented out, level-2 pages opened as pop ups work perfectly BUT when opened as free standing pages do NOT write their titles.  Obviously they are being rendered before the script is loaded.

My Tries to date:

-- Give up! Skip the code above.  Hard-code six additional  tags in  "/jsp-pages/level-2/headers/beg.jsp" that will reload the functions in the six JS files every time any level-2 page is opened Either way.

Ugly, inelegant, redundant, a waste if the page is opened as a pop-up, to be avoided at all cost.

-- When  TAPP is not this.opener, use DOM to load the JS files by adding script elements at the end of

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function   dynamicload(){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", "/scripts/banner.js");
    script.async = false;   // halt rendering until writeBanner() is loaded?
    head.appendChild(script);
    //alert ("DL Done");
  }
  dynamicload();
</script>
```

-- When TAPP is not this.opener, use document.write() to write the six scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  document.write('<SCR'+'IPT src="/scripts/banner.js '><\/SCR'+'IPT>');
  // and six more like it
</script>
```

So HELP!

Is it really NOT possible to use dynamically loaded functions to finish writing the page that dynamically loaded them?
glb

Comment: If you are only worried about "reload the functions in the six JS files every time any level-2 page is opened Either way" then why not just load each script all the time and modify each script file to check whether it has already been loaded and parsed? One method is to wrap the contents of each script in an `if` block like this: `if(!window.scriptXXXloaded) { window.scriptXXXloaded = true; .... your existing script... }`

Comment: Thank you.  But I don't think it will work.  Unless I missed something, all that does is swap 
Test A: if (this.opener && this.opener.name == "TAPP") for Test B: If (!window.scriptXXXLoaded).  Both tell me when the JS files are there.  Neither tells me how to dynamically add them only when they are not.  So ... looks like I will have to code all level-2 pages to load the JS files whether opened by TAPP, or opened as free standing pages.  Yes?

Comment: Yup. I do what you are doing all the time (pages can be opened in various contexts like this), and found that it is far easier to use the "include-once" pattern I mentioned as opposed to the complexity for implementation/maintenance of dynamic scripts. Besides easier maintenance it has the benefit of being agnostic with respect to the opener.

Comment: Sad I can't, but good to know for sure.  Wish I asked before spending a week thinking I was "almost there".

I just have to use two different includes for level-2 pages.  beg.jsp for pages always opened by a level-1 page (95%).  beg2.for the other 5%.  

I like your approach for other applications, but it won't help me with this.  Pages cannot decide for themselves whether to load the JS files while its loading and still have WriteBanner() in time to use it.  So if the function isn't loaded, I can't fix it anyway.  Have to load every time.  No big deal.  Just elegance suffers.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add things to the current page using dynamically loaded code.  But, you cannot use `document.write()` to do so.  You must add DOM elements directly to the page with methods like `.appendChild()` or `.insertBefore()` or set `.innerHTML` on an existing DOM element.

The problem with `document.write()` is that once the page had been loaded (and thus the document stream closed), any future calls to `document.write()` will clear the current page and start writing to a new, blank page which general ruins what you are trying to do.

And, when you dynamically load code, it will load AFTER the current document has finished loading.

`document.write()` is intended to insert content at the current location in the document stream while the document is in the process of loading which only works when the script is present in the original HTML either as a `<script>` tag or it can be used on a brand new document (such as the creation of a new `iframe` or new `window`).

Comment: I was afraid of that.  So the answer to my quest is NO.  A page cannot dynamically load JS script and use it to finish writing itself.  Any other suggestions for writing a page so it only loads script if its opener doesn't have it?

Comment: @George - Not really.   A page can finish writing itself with dynamically loaded scripts, just not with `document.write()`.  You can use other mechanisms for adding content to the page.

Comment: Hi. That would be great news... but if dynamically loaded code is loaded after the page is loaded writeBanner() will not be there yet to help write the Body while the page is being loaded.  So using DOM to add the Script tags doesn't work either.  Is there a 3rd way?

Comment: @George - you're asking individual technology questions which I'm trying to dutifully answer.  If you want to back up and describe your overall problem without proposing any solutions (just describe the problem), I'm sure a solution can be found, but I don't right now understand what problem you're really trying to solve so I don't know what direction to advise you.

Comment: My apologies.  I'll try again.  Level-2 pages use writeBanner() to write titles.  When opened as a pop-up by "TAPP" they use TAPP.writeBanner().  But when opened as a free standing page they must load JS files with writeBanner(). I want to dynamically load the JS files ONLY when they are opened as free standing pages.  But dynamically loaded JS files aren't loaded until the page is loaded, so any script that dynamically loads them will load them too late to write the tiles. Looks like I have no choice.  Code level-2 pages to always load the JS files, whether TAPP is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. You can't.

A page cannot load JS files with functions it needs to write the rest of the page.

No matter how you script to load the JS files -- add a script element with DOM, or write it in with document.write() -- the JS files end up being loaded AFTER the page is loaded when it is too late to write the page.  (See discussion with nothingnecessarey.)

However, it still bothers me that if I throw an alert() in my the script, both conditional approaches work – DOM and document.write() -- i.e. I had titles! All I can think of is the alert causes the page to re-render itself and since the alert is called after the page is loaded, the JS files are loaded.

Thanks to all for their help

AFTERTHOUGHT:  I dreamed that opening an empty page with an iFrame to load my level-2 might work.  If so I'll return.  If not ... I give up.